# redesigning of Angular-Wizard tabs

Tags: angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

I am learning Angular JS and now I am using Angular-Wizard. It works fine but I want to change the Tabs.

Yet it looks like this image:

[image: Angular Wizard Tabs standard version]

But I want the tabs to look a bit like this:

[image: Tabs version I want to have]

I managed to get the navbar on top with this template:

```
<div>
    <ul class="steps-indicator steps-{{getEnabledSteps().length}}" ng- 
    if="!hideIndicators">
        <li ng-class="{default: !step.completed && !step.selected, current: 
         step.selected && !step.completed, done: step.completed && 
         !step.selected, editing: step.selected && step.completed}" ng- 
         repeat="step in getEnabledSteps()">
            <a ng-click="goTo(step)">{{step.title || step.wzTitle}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div class="steps" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

But I want to get rid of the circles and get bootstrap like nav-tabs instead. I tried to change some things in the css files, but this seems not to help much.

Does anyone know which files I have to change, so that I can remove the circles and get nav-tabs like in bootstrap instead?

A link for a tutorial would be ok too. I know I could use another directive which fits more, but I want to learn changing existing directives.

Thanks in advance,
YB